# Solving the equation $AX+XA' = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am trying to solve the equation $AX + XA' = 0$ I could find how to solve when "$+$" is a "$-$" or $X$ is conjugated instead of $A$. Is there a solution for this problem too?

In particular, I am looking for a solution where all of the matrices are $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $A=BC$ where both B and C are hermitian symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: Please specify what are those $X$, $A$ and $A'$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation

Comment: This is a [countinuous Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $A^T$ is denoted by $A'$.

Since $A=BC$ and $B,C$ are hermit. $>0$, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $>0$ and the equation $AX+XA^T=0$ has a unique solution; of course, this solution is $X=0$.